# Hide Reply Button when ticket Closed

Tags: implementation, whmcs

I am running php-based support system called WHMCS

I am trying to prevent disabled tickets from being re-opened if closed .

Here is what I found in my php script system templates that's involved with this issue

**viewticket.tpl**

```
{if $invalidTicketId}

    {include file="$template/includes/alert.tpl" type="danger" title=$LANG.thereisaproblem msg=$LANG.supportticketinvalid textcenter=true}

{else}

    {if $closedticket}
        {include file="$template/includes/alert.tpl" type="warning" msg=$LANG.supportticketclosedmsg textcenter=true}
    {/if}

    {if $errormessage}
        {include file="$template/includes/alert.tpl" type="error" errorshtml=$errormessage}
    {/if}

{/if}

{if !$invalidTicketId}

    <div class="panel panel-info panel-collapsable{if !$postingReply} panel-collapsed{/if} hidden-print">
        <div class="panel-heading" id="ticketReply">
            <div class="collapse-icon pull-right">
                <i class="fa fa-{if !$postingReply}plus{else}minus{/if}"></i>
            </div>
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> &nbsp; {$LANG.supportticketsreply}
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body{if !$postingReply} panel-body-collapsed{/if}">

            <form method="post" action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?tid={$tid}&amp;c={$c}&amp;postreply=true" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" id="frmReply">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                        <label for="inputName">{$LANG.supportticketsclientname}</label>
                        {if $loggedin}
                            <input class="form-control disabled" type="text" id="inputName" value="{$clientname}" disabled="disabled" />{else}<input class="form-control" type="text" name="replyname" id="inputName" value="{$replyname}" />
                        {/if}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
                        <label for="inputEmail">{$LANG.supportticketsclientemail}</label>
                        {if $loggedin}
                            <input class="form-control disabled" type="text" id="inputEmail" value="{$email}" disabled="disabled" />{else}<input class="form-control" type="text" name="replyemail" id="inputEmail" value="{$replyemail}" />
                        {/if}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputMessage">{$LANG.contactmessage}</label>
                    <textarea name="replymessage" id="inputMessage" rows="12" class="form-control">{$replymessage}</textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <label for="inputAttachments">{$LANG.supportticketsticketattachments}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="file" name="attachments[]" id="inputAttachments" class="form-control" />
                        <div id="fileUploadsContainer"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" onclick="extraTicketAttachment()">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> {$LANG.addmore}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 ticket-attachments-message text-muted">
                        {$LANG.supportticketsallowedextensions}: {$allowedfiletypes}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="save" value="{$LANG.supportticketsticketsubmit}" />
                    <input class="btn btn-default" type="reset" value="{$LANG.cancel}" onclick="jQuery('#ticketReply').click()" />
                </div>

            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

    {foreach from=$descreplies key=num item=reply}
        <div class="ticket-reply{if $reply.admin} staff{/if}">
            <div class="date">
                {$reply.date}
            </div>
            <div class="user">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                <span class="name">
                    {$reply.name}
                </span>
                <span class="type">
                    {if $reply.admin}
                        {$LANG.supportticketsstaff}
                    {elseif $reply.contactid}
                        {$LANG.supportticketscontact}
                    {elseif $reply.userid}
                        {$LANG.supportticketsclient}
                    {else}
                        {$reply.email}
                    {/if}
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="message">
                {$reply.message}
                {if $reply.id && $reply.admin && $ratingenabled}
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        {if $reply.rating}
                            <div class="rating-done">
                                {for $rating=1 to 5}
                                    <span class="star{if (5 - $reply.rating) < $rating} active{/if}"></span>
                                {/for}
                                <div class="rated">{$LANG.ticketreatinggiven}</div>
                            </div>
                        {else}
                            <div class="rating" ticketid="{$tid}" ticketkey="{$c}" ticketreplyid="{$reply.id}">
                                <span class="star" rate="5"></span>
                                <span class="star" rate="4"></span>
                                <span class="star" rate="3"></span>
                                <span class="star" rate="2"></span>
                                <span class="star" rate="1"></span>
                            </div>
                        {/if}
                    </div>
                {/if}
            </div>
            {if $reply.attachments}
                <div class="attachments">
                    <strong>{$LANG.supportticketsticketattachments} ({$reply.attachments|count})</strong>
                    <ul>
                        {foreach from=$reply.attachments key=num item=attachment}
                            <li><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> <a href="dl.php?type={if $reply.id}ar&id={$reply.id}{else}a&id={$id}{/if}&i={$num}">{$attachment}</a></li>
                        {/foreach}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            {/if}
        </div>
    {/foreach}

{/if}
```

I managed to get the code that able to close the ticket permanentlybut i don't know where exactly i should put this code in viewticket.tpl

Here is the code that can make ticket closed not open again

```
{if $status eq "Closed"} This ticket has been closed, please open a new ticket.
{else}
{/if}
```

Hope someone help me regard this problem , i can provide more information if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the following - you also will need to edit the language string for the closed ticket since it says you can reply to reopen - but this is the code you want to use:

```html
{if $invalidTicketId}
{include file="$template/includes/alert.tpl" type="danger" title=$LANG.thereisaproblem msg=$LANG.supportticketinvalid textcenter=true}
{else}
{if $closedticket}
    {include file="$template/includes/alert.tpl" type="warning" msg=$LANG.supportticketclosedmsg textcenter=true}
{/if}
{if $errormessage}
    {include file="$template/includes/alert.tpl" type="error" errorshtml=$errormessage}
{/if}
{/if}

{if !$invalidTicketId}

<div class="{if !$closedticket}panel panel-info panel-collapsable{if !$postingReply} panel-collapsed{/if} hidden-print{/if}">
    {if ! $closedticket}<div class="panel-heading" id="ticketReply">
        <div class="collapse-icon pull-right">
            <i class="fa fa-{if !$postingReply}plus{else}minus{/if}"></i>
        </div>
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> &nbsp; {$LANG.supportticketsreply}
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body{if !$postingReply} panel-body-collapsed{/if}">

        <form method="post" action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?tid={$tid}&amp;c={$c}&amp;postreply=true" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" id="frmReply">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                    <label for="inputName">{$LANG.supportticketsclientname}</label>
                    {if $loggedin}
                        <input class="form-control disabled" type="text" id="inputName" value="{$clientname}" disabled="disabled" />{else}<input class="form-control" type="text" name="replyname" id="inputName" value="{$replyname}" />
                    {/if}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
                    <label for="inputEmail">{$LANG.supportticketsclientemail}</label>
                    {if $loggedin}
                        <input class="form-control disabled" type="text" id="inputEmail" value="{$email}" disabled="disabled" />{else}<input class="form-control" type="text" name="replyemail" id="inputEmail" value="{$replyemail}" />
                    {/if}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputMessage">{$LANG.contactmessage}</label>
                <textarea name="replymessage" id="inputMessage" rows="12" class="form-control">{$replymessage}</textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <label for="inputAttachments">{$LANG.supportticketsticketattachments}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="file" name="attachments[]" id="inputAttachments" class="form-control" />
                    <div id="fileUploadsContainer"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" onclick="extraTicketAttachment()">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> {$LANG.addmore}
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 ticket-attachments-message text-muted">
                    {$LANG.supportticketsallowedextensions}: {$allowedfiletypes}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="save" value="{$LANG.supportticketsticketsubmit}" />
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="reset" value="{$LANG.cancel}" onclick="jQuery('#ticketReply').click()" />
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>
 {/if}
</div>
    

{foreach from=$descreplies key=num item=reply}
    <div class="ticket-reply{if $reply.admin} staff{/if}">
        <div class="date">
            {$reply.date}
        </div>
        <div class="user">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            <span class="name">
                {$reply.name}
            </span>
            <span class="type">
                {if $reply.admin}
                    {$LANG.supportticketsstaff}
                {elseif $reply.contactid}
                    {$LANG.supportticketscontact}
                {elseif $reply.userid}
                    {$LANG.supportticketsclient}
                {else}
                    {$reply.email}
                {/if}
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
            {$reply.message}
            {if $reply.id && $reply.admin && $ratingenabled}
                <div class="clearfix">
                    {if $reply.rating}
                        <div class="rating-done">
                            {for $rating=1 to 5}
                                <span class="star{if (5 - $reply.rating) < $rating} active{/if}"></span>
                            {/for}
                            <div class="rated">{$LANG.ticketreatinggiven}</div>
                        </div>
                    {else}
                        <div class="rating" ticketid="{$tid}" ticketkey="{$c}" ticketreplyid="{$reply.id}">
                            <span class="star" rate="5"></span>
                            <span class="star" rate="4"></span>
                            <span class="star" rate="3"></span>
                            <span class="star" rate="2"></span>
                            <span class="star" rate="1"></span>
                        </div>
                    {/if}
                </div>
            {/if}
        </div>
        {if $reply.attachments}
            <div class="attachments">
                <strong>{$LANG.supportticketsticketattachments} ({$reply.attachments|count})</strong>
                <ul>
                    {foreach from=$reply.attachments key=num item=attachment}
                        <li><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> <a href="dl.php?type={if $reply.id}ar&id={$reply.id}{else}a&id={$id}{/if}&i={$num}">{$attachment}</a></li>
                    {/foreach}
                </ul>
            </div>
        {/if}
    </div>
{/foreach}

{/if}
```